# django-compressor: Using lessc in DEBUG mode

Tags: django, less, django-compressor

I'm not sure I'm doing things right, but here's the issue:

- I'm using `django-compressor` with the `lessc` preprocessor
- Some of the LESS files have relative image URLs. Some are mine, some are 3rd party libraries (*e.g.* Bootstrap)
- When `COMPRESS_ENABLED` is `True`, all is working fine
- When `COMPRESS_ENABLED` is `False`, the `CssAbsoluteFilter` is not running anymore, which means all relative image URLs are kept relative and are therefore broken (since they're not relative from the `CACHE` directory)

I could come up with a "clever" directory structure where relative paths resolve to the same file whether they originate from the `CACHE` directory or from the LESS files directory, but that seems like a brittle workaround.

How do you usually work when it comes to LESS + `django-compressor`?

Comment: Seems like a bug in django_compressor to me - the precompilers always get called, but the filters only happen when compressing.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happens -- so not a bug, as it works as documented. But since it's not what's *desired*, IMHO, I'm wondering if I'm missing something or just using it wrong.

Comment: Seems like it's a case that just hasn't been considered by the django_compressor devs... it's definitely an issue, if not a bug. Have you tried writing a precompiler script to convert your urls?

Comment: See a bug report on this issue here: https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor/issues/226

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a simple workaround:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/less', 'path.to.precompilers.LessFilter'),
)
```

precompilers.py:

```
from compressor.filters.base import CompilerFilter
from compressor.filters.css_default import CssAbsoluteFilter

class LessFilter(CompilerFilter):
    def __init__(self, content, attrs, **kwargs):
        super(LessFilter, self).__init__(content, command='lessc {infile} {outfile}', **kwargs)

    def input(self, **kwargs):
        content = super(LessFilter, self).input(**kwargs)
        return CssAbsoluteFilter(content).input(**kwargs)
```

Please note this works with both `COMPRESS_ENABLED = True` and `False`.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in django-compressor 1.6. From the [changelog](https://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changelog/):

```
Apply CssAbsoluteFilter to precompiled css even when compression is disabled
```

i.e. the absolute filter is run on your less files even with DEBUG = True.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using django-libsass the filter code looks like this:

```
from compressor.filters.css_default import CssAbsoluteFilter
from django_libsass import SassCompiler


class PatchedSCSSCompiler(SassCompiler):
    def input(self, **kwargs):
        content = super(PatchedSCSSCompiler, self).input(**kwargs)
        return CssAbsoluteFilter(content).input(**kwargs)
```

And then in your settings file:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/x-scss', 'path.to.PatchedSCSSCompiler'),
)
```